# Securing password client side Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, security, authentication, firebase

I'm currently following this [Email & Password Authentication tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html) from Firebase.

Here is the basic code for logging in with email and password:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

For each page I navigate through on my website, do I need to re-authenticate with the email and password credentials to access the database?

And if so, how do I pass the `email` and `password` through the web pages without making the password vulnerable to exposure.

I'm very new to security, and don't want to run in to any security issues or data leaks, hence the reason I'm relying on third-party services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase persists the authentication state in the browser when you call:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.error("Login Failed!", error);
  } 
});
```

To retrieve the persisted authentication state on a page reload, you can use the `onAuth()` method:

```
// this will fire even if not authenticated and authData
// will be null
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log(authData.uid);
  }
});
```

As far as security goes, Firebase requires HTTPS connections so all emails and passwords are encrypted going over the wire.